Cap for shaving cream stuck down my showers pipe
There is a cap the width of my pipe stuck down my pipe, i can’t reach it with my fingers. Any advice, ill try upload a photo

Can you reach it with the flat end of the vacuum cleaner hose?

Also How do I remove a bottle cap stuck 3 feet down a drain line

Also How can I remove the stopper from my sink?

Take a piece of string and tie it around the head of a drywall screw. Stick the screw to a long screwdriver/magnetic screwdriver. Screw the screw into the cap and pull up the screwdriver or pull the string.

+1 for creativity. Have you done this?

@gnicko  Yes I have. I have probably done for me or for someone else  95% of what I've posted over the last 5 years

I assumed so. I just wondered if this was one of those other 5% ones. Either way, I almost want to try this...

Or, depending how the cap is stuck, you can try to drop the screw down the drain past the cap, and pull it up.
